# Accessibility bugs in Safari

Tags: safari, accessibility, voiceover

I am trying to fix accessibility bugs that are related to VoiceOver where screen reader doesn't read the list item from the drop down. This is the custom Combobox which is similar to Material UI components. I tried different ways by adding the role, and aria attribute to the parent but was not successful. The issue only happens in Safari and the rest of browsers are working as expected. Has anyone ran into this problem in the past and what was the solution?

I would be appreciated for the help.

Thanks,
Dara

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Browsers build their AOM (accessibility object model) differently, as a limited set of the DOM so check the AOM first in the Accessibility inspector to see what Safari is providing the screenreader. Use Chrome to try to find a11y errors using the SiteImprove extension, it's great.

Comment: @Nathaniel thanks. I'll take a look at this extension.

Comment: @slugolicious sorry I cannot share the code here. It's against company policy.

Comment: You want us to help your code so you need to post something for us to look at. Make a simpler example that you can post. Or find a Material example that has the same problem and post that.  We can’t guess at what you need because there are lots of ways for the code to be inaccessible.